# how to convert/split a list of strings into columns to be used in sql in spark java

Tags: java, sql, list, apache-spark

i have a List=["a","b","c"] and i need to split this list into strings to use them like :

SELECT columns

i tried

```
String.join(",",["a","b","c"])
```

but i obtain usually the same error (because i think that it's seen like an only column) :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`a,b,c`'
```

plz how can split the list to multiple strings to use them in my select

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: the expected output is a,b,c, i obtain this but the problem that i can't apply a select from, i have an error

Comment: You mean you don't know how to use a loop to get element by element ?

Comment: no, i need to SELECT a,b,c FROM df but i have an error because it is seen like an only column "a,b,c" and not multiple columns, i search to know how can i correct this

Comment: Read out the doc , how to convert list to string https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-to-string

Answer (score 0):

your written code has problem where you passed an array of values which you have to write it as below:

```
String value = String.join(",", new String[] {"a","b","c"});
System.out.println(value);
```